# Google KMS on AppEngine Dev Server - logging clutter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-kms

> This is a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63253097

Further to [my question about getting Google KMS working with App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826934/google-kms-on-appengine-python-development-appserver), I'm opening a new question about a related but problematic side effect.

Namely, the Google Cloud API discovery appears to want to walk a number of paths outside the AppEngine sandbox.  This itself is not a problem, but it makes testing and debugging very problematic because each attempt is logged, producing hundreds of lines like the following:

> INFO  03 Jul 2017 14:44:51  Sandbox prevented access to file "/Users"
>
> INFO  03 Jul 2017 14:44:51  If it is a static file, check that `application_readable: true` is set in your app.yaml
>
> INFO  03 Jul 2017 14:44:52  Sandbox prevented access to file "/usr/lib/Acrobat9/Resource/CMap"
>
> INFO  03 Jul 2017 14:44:52  If it is a static file, check that `application_readable: true` is set in your app.yaml
>
> INFO  03 Jul 2017 14:44:52  Sandbox prevented access to file "/usr/lib/Acrobat8/Resource/CMap"
>
> INFO  03 Jul 2017 14:44:52  If it is a static file, check that `application_readable: true` is set in your app.yaml

Is there a way to disable or silence these requests or logs?

**EDIT*** One of the many results printed by adding `traceback.print_stack()` to `log_access_check_fail` in `stub.py` (sorry it's not very legible here):

#### Test #1: Sentry.io's Raven imports `pkg_resources`

```
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/application.py", line 3, in <module>
    from nassau.application import app, sentry
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/nassau/application.py", line 28, in <module>
    from raven.contrib.flask import Sentry
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    VERSION = __import__('pkg_resources') \
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3037, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3021, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3050, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 646, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 639, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 695, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2006, in find_on_path
    path_item = _normalize_cached(path_item)
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2217, in _normalize_cached
    _cache[filename] = result = normalize_path(filename)
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2210, in normalize_path
    return os.path.normcase(os.path.realpath(filename))
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 375, in realpath
    path, ok = _joinrealpath('', filename, {})
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 400, in _joinrealpath
    if not islink(newpath):
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 135, in islink
    st = os.lstat(path)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/stubs.py", line 286, in __call__
    log_access_check_fail(path)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/stubs.py", line 51, in log_access_check_fail
    traceback.print_stack()
```

I removed the dependency on Sentry / Raven, but the stack traces continue, via:

#### Test #2: Flask imports `pkgutil`

```
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/application.py", line 3, in <module>
    from nassau.application import app
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/nassau/application.py", line 72, in <module>
    app = Flask('nassau')
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 331, in __init__
    instance_path = self.auto_find_instance_path()
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 622, in auto_find_instance_path
    prefix, package_path = find_package(self.import_name)
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 661, in find_package
    loader = pkgutil.get_loader(root_mod_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 464, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 475, in find_loader
    loader = importer.find_module(fullname)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 184, in find_module
    path = [os.path.realpath(self.path)]
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 375, in realpath
    path, ok = _joinrealpath('', filename, {})
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 400, in _joinrealpath
    if not islink(newpath):
  File "/Users/bmh/testapp/python-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 135, in islink
    st = os.lstat(path)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/stubs.py", line 286, in __call__
    log_access_check_fail(path)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/stubs.py", line 51, in log_access_check_fail
    traceback.print_stack()
```

There must be a better way to represent a stack trace on stack overflow :)

Comment: I've noticed this on the most recent "traditional" sdk (1.9.56).  I've to investigate whether these messages can be suppressed without suppressing other, useful log messages.  But I can say that they don't appear in 1.9.50, so if downgrading your sdk is acceptable you could do that.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Great idea, using gcloud how do you downgrade? Thanks!

Comment: @Shaun `gcloud components update --version xxx.x.x` will upgrade or downgrade the entire gcloud sdk to the provided version; I don't see a way to upgrade or downgrade specific subcomponents.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: @Shaun added [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45044637/1953800) to filter out these messages without needing to downgrade gcloud

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a fulltime engineer working on dev_appserver.
This log message is reported from /google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/stubs.py, in the method `log_access_check_fail`

We added this log message to remind users of dev_appserver's behavior of blocking file access.

Recommended workaround:
 dev_appserver.py   --log_level warning

--log_level sets the log level in local python runtime process. The log_access_check_fail() is set to INFO and would not be logged. NOTE, this flag will also prevent other INFO level logging in your application.

Meanwhile, we are working on a fix to this log_access_check_fail method. It could be lowering log_access_check_fail() logging level to DEBUG.

Comment: Thanks Kai.  FWIW, I think log-access failures can be useful debugging info, so it might be better not to disable them entirely (or perhaps make them optionally enabled with a flag); a better answer might be fixing the discovery API (if possible) to not check outside the dev_appserver habitat.

Comment: Hi Brian, I agree with the necessity of log-access.  Actually, when trying to replicate your issue (on Mac OS & Ubuntu) with the mykms.py [1]. I did not see attempts to access with "/Users" or "/usr/lib/Acrobat9/Resource/CMap".  Could you confirm these attempts are made by discovery api, instead of oauthclient2 or your application code? Thanks                                                                                                                 [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44826934/google-kms-on-appengine-python-development-appserver

Comment: @KaiWang, I see the `/usr/lib/Acrobat...` log messages in apps that import the [reportlab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab) package.

Comment: @KaiWang is there a public bug report where we can comment on this behaviour?  I have more comments on this but SO comments aren't the best location for this discussion.

Comment: @KaiWang It could indeed by oauthclient2 — The issue began when I started using the discovery API, but it could indeed be via the oauth2.  We do also include reportlab - but that has been in there for years.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a stacktrace.  It looks like a lot of things are triggering the access issue.  Let me know if something other than the stacktrace would help illuminate.

Comment: @snakecharmerb to report GAE public bug/issue, go to this page: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#bug_reports  and there's a hyperlink 'Create new App Engine issue'

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt  Admittedly KMS is not the only one triggering the access issue. I'd recommend opening a public issue at Google Cloud Platform's public issue tracker -- it is easier for issue triage, official technical support and also formatting stacktrace :)

Answer (score 3):

This is quite annoying and there is a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63253097) for it.

In the meantime we can filter out these messages but we need to figure out which `logger` they are using. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) for more info on how logging records are handled. Taking a look at the source for `stubs.py` I found:

```
logging.info('Sandbox prevented access to file "%s"', filename)
logging.info('If it is a static file, check that '
           '`application_readable: true` is set in your app.yaml')
```

So they are using the root logger (bad practice generally). To filter out these messages on your root logger add the following to your `appengine_config.py`:

```
import logging

class StubsFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        return 'stubs.py' != record.filename

logging.root.addFilter(StubsFilter())
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, these messages appear to originate from a GAE (.local) file called stubs.py.

1. In my first case, stubs.py was looking for files that were not there. So you might want to check to see if  "/usr/lib/Acrobat8/Resource/CMap" actually exists. Then, starting with stubs.py, try to find out [what file is trying to load it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837374/google-app-engine-ubuntu-14-04-urlfetch-500-200-issue-python-2-7/44873610#44873610).

   2. My project is using web.py, all of a sudden I started getting (stubs.py) messages again, this time about .pyc files. I put a [skip_files:](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) in the bottom of my app.yaml file, and it does suppress the messages, but I haven't tested to see if my app still fully compiles.

      ```
      skip_files:
      - ^(.*/)?\.pyc$
      ```

More on the Python GAE runtime and sandbox here.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime